# Silverman Elliptic Curves Exercise 1.8

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*.I was trying to solve exercise 1.8 but I'm stuck.

> 1.8. Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with *q* elements and let $V\subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ be a variety defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
> (a) Prove that the $q^{th}$ power map
> $\phi = [X_{0}^{q}
> , . . . , X_{n}^{q}
> ]$
> is a morphism.
> (b) Prove that $\phi$ is one-to-one and onto.
> (c) Prove that $\phi$ is not an isomorphism.
> (d)Prove that $V(\mathbb{F}_{q})=$ $\{P\in V:\phi(P)=P\}$

(a)Now a point of $V$ is of the form $[X_{0},...,X_{n}]$ where $X_{i}\in \overline{\mathbb{F}_{q}}$.Then for some $i,k>0$,$X_{i} \in \mathbb{F}_{q^{k_{i}}}$.Then $X_{i}^{q}=0 \iff X_{i}=0$.Therefore,$\phi$ is a morphism since it is regular everywhere.

(b)As before for some $i,k>0$,$X_{i} \in \mathbb{F}_{q^{k_{i}}}$.Then $X_{i}^{q^{k_{i}}}=X_{i}$.Then $X_{i}^{q^{k_{i}-1}}=1$.Take $Y_{i}=X_{i}^{q^{k_{i}-1}}$.This shows $\phi$ is onto.

(d)$V(\mathbb{F_{q}})\subset \{P\in V:\phi(P)=P\}$ is clear.For other inclusion,for some $i,k>0$,let $X_{i} \in \mathbb{F}_{q^{k_{i}}}$; $X_{i}^{q^{k_{i}}}=X_{i}=X_{i}^{q}$,then $k_{i}=1$(?).
I'm not sure how to show injection and part(c).

Comment: (b) is not quite true: $Y_i=X_i^{q^{k_i-1}}$ is correct, but it’s $X_i^{q^{k_i}-1}$ that is $1$ (or $0$). (d) is false as well: $[X_i^q]_i=[X_i]_i$ only means that there is a nonzero $\lambda \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ such that $X_i^q=\lambda X_i$ for all $i$. Show that you can write $\lambda=y^q/y$ for some nonzero $y$.

Comment: Can't believe I messed up the definition of projective space in (d). Thanks! Any idea about one-one and (c)?

Comment: One-to-one is really about unrolling definitions. Let $[x_i]_i,[y_i]_i$ be such that $(x_i^q)_i=\lambda (y_i^q)_i$, then try to show that $x,y$ are proportional. I’m much less sure for (c). I think you can reduce to the case of an affine variety $V’$, and then show that taking $q$-th power $\mathbb{F}_q[V’] \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q[V’]$ is not onto.

Answer (score 0):

Part (c): to be precise, the exercise is false as stated; you need to assume $\dim V>0$. Indeed, when $V$ is a point, $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Now assume $\dim V>0$. Affine locally, the morphism $\phi$ is given by a ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to A:x\mapsto x^p$, where $A$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb F_q$-algebra (in fact, an integral domain). Then, Theorem 8.6A of Hartshorne tells us $\Omega_{A/\mathbb F_q}$ is nonzero. But the differential $df\colon \Omega_{A/\mathbb F_q}\to \Omega_{A/\mathbb F_q}$ of $f$ is zero, since $d(a^p)=pa^{p-1}da=0$. Thus $f$ cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks!Is there a more elementary way to go about it?I haven't read differentials yet and it comes up in chapter 2 of Silverman and this exercise comes up in chapter 1.